# defining a class constructor

Tags: c++, class, constructor

I'm dealing with my very first course on programming in C++ and that's the way in which I've been told to define a class constructor:

```
class_name(int x, int y){
    this->x=x;
    this->y=y;
  };
```

If I understood correctly, as I've found several times here, I could rewrite it this way:

```
field(int x, int y) : m_x(x), m_y(y){};
```

having however this protected variables:

```
protected:
    int m_x, m_y;
```

instead of

```
protected:
    int x, y;
```

Are there any differences between them or is it just different ways of writing?

And, if so, why the need of having different *m_x* and *x* variables?

I hope this is not such a silly questions, but I'd like to really understand it.

peace.

Comment: `field(int x, int y) : x(x), y(y){};` works either, but may look more confusing and is perhaps a bad practice, see **@DeiDei**'s comment.

Comment: @AlexD Shadowing is evil.

Comment: @DeiDei Updated, to make the comments recursive :).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Q1. Should I use a constructor [initializer list](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/initializer_list) or initialize in the body of the constructor?

There are 2 reasons why a constructor intializer list is the best choice where possible:

1. `const` members, reference members, and member objects without default constructors can only be initialized in a constructor intializer list
2. Member objects which are initialized in the body of the constructor must be default constructed and then initialized separately; which misses out on optimization opportunities and prevents those objects from having any of the members called out in **1**

### Q2. Should I use a naming convention for member variables?

Yes. Google, [for example](https://google.github.io/styleguide/cppguide.html#Variable_Names), recommends naming member variables with a trailing underscore, but an `m_` prefix accomplishes the same goal of saving the reader the time of looking up whether this variable was declared in the current scope, or whether this variable is a member variable.

Answer (score 1):

the first type of initializing x and y is inside a the constructor body and the second you used member initializer-list.

they are the same but there are where you must use member-list initializer when using inheritance so you can't call the base constructor inside the body of derived class's constructor definition. eg:

```
class A
{
    public:
        A(int x) : _x(x){} // ok
//      A(int x) {_x = x;} ok
    protected:
        int _x;
};

class B : public A
{
    public:
    //  B(int x) {A(x);} error here
        B(int x) : A(x){} // we must use member initializer list here
};
```